# Fulton Exercise 1.31 finding irreducible components

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is Fulton, Algebraic Curves exercise 1.31:

We have to find irreducible components of $V(f) =V(y^2-xy-x^2y+x^3)$ in $\mathbb{A^2({\mathbb{R}})}$ and $\mathbb{A^2({\mathbb{C}})}$.

My attempt: 
Is to write this polynomial as = $(y-x^2)(y-x)$
And so we have $V(f)= V(y-x^2) \cup V(y-x)$
My guess is that it would be the same set of points in both $\mathbb{A^2({\mathbb{R}})}$ and $\mathbb{A^2({\mathbb{C}})}$.

Is my guess correct? Any alternate approach or output on my idea will be appreciated, thanks.

$V(f)$ denotes the set of all points at which $f$ is zero in  $\mathbb{A^2({\mathbb{k}})}$, $k$ a field.

Comment: What do you mean, the same set of points? Consider $(i,i)$, for example.

Comment: Oh, yeah you are right.

Comment: Any hint on how to explicitly find those sets? In case of $\mathbb{R}$, it's obvious that it will be union of a parabola and a line.  I don't know what I can do in complex case.

Comment: You've correctly identified them in this case, for both fields. Think about the correspondence between varieties and ideals: if some polynomial $g$ divides $f$, this means that $(f)\subset (g)$, and so $V(g)\subset V(f)$. Since irreducible components correspond to prime ideals, the question is asking you to find all prime factors of $f$, which you did.